# Django-Allauth: How to authenticate users via Chrome extension?

Tags: django, google-chrome-extension, django-allauth

I'm building a Django web app with `django-allauth` handling user authentication.

As title, how do you expose a RESTful API to authenticate users from a Chrome extension? Taking into account of both:

1. `locally stored username & password hash string pairs` and
2. `third party social log-in providers`?

What is the best or simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution to be Django-Rest-Framework.

I installed DRF, and wrote a serializer for my User model and an API view to handle token authentication.